# How to create a strand count?

Tags: python, string

How to create a .py file using the information below to make it test. The example is a dockets.py formatted, but I need to original file with .py not test.py or dockets.py.

RNA Nucleotide Strand Count

Implement a function rna_strand_count(dna, strands) that takes two parameters, dna (a string) and strands (a list of strings), and returns a dictionary whose keys are the individual strings in strands and values are the number of occurances of those strings in the RNA complement transcribed from the original DNA.

```
>> rna_strand_count('AAAA', ['AA'])
{'AA': 3}
```

The function shall meet these conditions:

rna_count should be able to handle DNA strings in either upper or lowercase form and return the dictionary with keys in the form given
rna_count should also be robust to whitespace:
Whitespace can be assumed not to be part of a strand
For the purpose of counting strands, whitespace in the DNA string can be stripped
A complete set of unit tests for this function shall be included, using both the unittest and doctest modules.

Comment: What's your attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: import unittest

from dna import rna_strand_count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you want this:

```
import re

def rna_strand_count(test_string,sub_string):
    test_string = test_string.replace(' ','').upper()    
    sub_string = sub_string.replace(' ','').upper()    
    first = sub_string[0]
    second = sub_string[1:]
    return {sub_string:len(re.findall(r'{0}(?={1})'.format(first,second),test_string))}


print rna_strand_count('AAAA','AA')
```

Comment: Thanks Ahsanul Haque